# RecyclerView Not Displaying Data Correctly After Scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am building a native android application.  I have a service that returns a list of items from the server.  I would like to take the data received and add this to a recycler view (only TextViews for now).  Upon initial load of the activity and data the RecyclerView displays the data correctly.  However, when I start to scroll it seems to stop binding the data to the views and the list looks blank.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my Adapter

```
public class SearchItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchItemAdapter.SearchItemViewHolder> {



@Override
public SearchItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    this.context = parent.getContext();
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.search_item_result_cell, parent, false);
    return new SearchItemViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ItemSearchResult searchResult = searchResults.get(position);
    holder.bindSearchData(searchResult);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return searchResults.size();
}


public SearchItemAdapter(List<ItemSearchResult> searchResults) {
    this.searchResults = searchResults;
}

public static class SearchItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView description;
    private TextView regularPrice;
    private TextView salePrice;
    private TextView aisle;

    public SearchItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        regularPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.regular_price);
        salePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sale_price);
        aisle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aisle);
    }

    public void bindSearchData(ItemSearchResult searchResult) {
        aisle.setText(searchResult.getAisle());
        salePrice.setText(searchResult.getAd());
        regularPrice.setText(searchResult.getRegular());
        description.setText(searchResult.getDescription());
    }
}
```

}

Here is some code from my activity initializing the data and the view

```
private RecyclerView mSearchResultRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_search);
    mSearchResultRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_search_recycler_view);
    searchTerms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_terms);

}

@Subscribe
public void displaySearchResults(SearchItemResultEvent event) {
    mAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(event.getSearchResults());
    mSearchResultRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mSearchResultRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

}
```

Comment: Do you call the `displaySearchResults(SearchItemResultEvent event)` method all the time? How do you insert new elements into the adapter? Do you call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` anywhere in the code? How does the Subscriber-Publisher pattern come in here (I can see you annotated your display method with @Subscribe)?

Comment: displaySearchResult is only called one time.  I am initializing the the SearchItemAdapter with an already initialized list of a fixed number of elements.  `@Subscribe` is an annotation used with Otto, I forgot to take this out.  It basically means that once I receive the search items I post an SearchItemResultEvent and `@Subscribe` tells tells the method to "listen" for that event.  Hope this makes sense.  **Edit - You should also know that the activity is already initialized by the time this method is called.

Comment: Try providing getItemId() implementation.

Comment: I tried to implement getItemId() still no luck

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is there data enough to show after scrolling? Did you try debugging to see if onBindViewHolder is called after you scroll?

Comment: Not a silly question, but there is plenty of data to display after scrolling. I have noticed that onBindViewHolder is only called once when I scroll.  So to be clear, it is called on each item for the initial view load and only one time after.  It loads only one item "out of view" and then it stops loading/showing data.

Comment: 1. try changing the setLayoutManager with setAdapter()
2. what about the layout? maybe the RecyclerView is within anything like ScrollView?

Comment: 1.  I'm assuming you mean change the order in with they are set, this does nothing.  2.  It is a child view of a relative layout, no scroll views are in the layout file.

Comment: there seems nothing wrong with your code, I have several similar places - all work ok. The only thing not visible - is your layout hierarchy, so I'd dig there.

Comment: What @khusrav said. Or maybe if it is not sensitive work, put it up on GitHub and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies. After several hours of banging my head, I just used the old school style ListView.  It's working as expected.